Si la luna mengua para crecer por qué no puede ser que tú y yo
¿Qué significa "si la luna mengua para crecer" en "si la luna mengua para crecer por qué no puede ser que tú y yo"
Entiendo que "menguar" significa diminuir or empequeñecer. ¿Significaría la frase entonces "si la luna diminuye/empequeñece para crecer?" ¿Pero en este caso qué tiene que ver con la segunda frase "por qué no puede ser que tú y yo? ¡ Muchas gracias !

@tac el autor no deja la frase incompleta, justo he hablado de ello en mi respuesta.

la luna va por ciclos, tiene que diminuir para después crescer.  ¿Y donde está el resto de la frase?

Podemos hablar del sentido literal de la frase: Si la luna mengua para crecer
Su significado vendría a ser algo como:
Si la luna [disminuye (de tamaño)|encoge|decrece|se achica|se ve más pequeña] para crecer.
El diccionario de la RAE define mengua como "la Acción y efecto de menguar" y el verbo menguar:


Dicho de una cosa: Disminuir o irse consumiendo física o moralmente
Dicho de la Luna: Disminuir su parte iluminada visible desde la Tierra.


La misma entrada del diccionario nos da sinónimos de Disminuir:

aminorar, mermar, encoger, decrecer, achicar, reducir, descrecer

Por otro lado, se hace alusión específicamente a la luna porque una de las fases de la luna se llama cuarto menguante y es, justamente, cuando la parte visible de la luna se va haciendo más pequeña, por lo que las palabras suelen relacionarse con frecuencia.

Ya de la parte poética, el único que podría responder lo que tenía en mente y con qué sentido la usó es el autor.
Lo que puedo aportar es que el autor no deja la idea inconclusa, como podría parecer al leer la pregunta, sino que completa el simil.
Lo que ocurre es que está intercalado con un par de versos, que haría falta quitar para entender lo que dice. Los he tachado aquí:
Mi querida isabel
si la luna
mengua para crecer
por qué no puede ser
que tú y yo
Isabel, Isabel
mi querida Isabel
como lunas
nos podamos sumar
para amarnos más y mejor
Puedes leer la letra omitiendo esas líneas y cobrará el sentido que quiso darle el autor.
No quiero emitir mi opinión sobre la calidad de la letra o del recurso literario, quise hacer la anotación solo para que te quede más clara la intención del escritor.
Para responder a tu pregunta únicamente con la lógica y tratando de no poner sentimiento:

¿... qué tiene que ver con la segunda frase "por qué no puede ser que tú y yo?

Pues, en realidad, aún con el símil completo, en mi opinión, no tiene sentido.
A ver,
si algo se hace más pequeño para crecer <--suponiendo que eso fuera cierto
por qué no puede ser que tú y yo nos sumemos para amarnos.
Bfff... no tiene sentido, vamos de regreso, si tú y yo nos sumamos, no nos estamos haciendo más pequeños para crecer, ni nada similar. Es cierto que sumados somos más grandes (por tratar de emparejar la lógica), pero nada se ha hecho más pequeño, ni una cosa es producto de la otra.
Fallas lógicas por todos lados...
Vamos, es poesía, si a tí te hace sentir algo, o lo interpretas de otra forma, es totalmente válido.

A mi, que me gusta la ciencia en general y la física en particular, si puedo decir que la frase es, cuando menos, desafortunada y muy imprecisa. La luna no crece ni decrece, siempre es del mismo tamaño. (Lo siento por los que creen en los efectos de la luna llena en las mareas, no se diga en las plantas y otras yerbas).
Es cierto que sus efectos varían al acercarse y alejarse de la tierra en su órbita, y que al estar más lejos naturalmente se vería más pequeña pero el cambio es muy pequeño para poder apreciarse a simple vista.
El hacerse visiblemente su parte iluminada más pequeña y más grande es parte del ciclo lunar, pero no tiene una relación de causalidad. Estrictamente hablando, la luna no debe hacerse más pequeña, para poder hacerse más grande. Son cosas que ocurren en secuencia, nada más.

"A mi, que me gusta la ciencia en general y la física en particular, si puedo decir que la frase es, cuando menos, desafortunada y muy imprecisa", querer aplicar lógica a la poesía, es decididamente erróneo, por otro lado, no se debe leer literalmente lo escrito, hay que interpretarlo, y ahí, se habre un mundo de posibilidades, podemos interpretar de forma distinta la misma frase, y esa es la "magia", como bien dices, "si a tí te hace sentir algo", esa es la finalidad.

Vaya poesia. Mira: la luna va por ciclos, tiene que diminuir para después crescer. Si ellos se suman, van a diminiuir y después crescer juntos. O sea, lo bueno y lo malo=casarse, por lo visto.

@Lambie jaja yo pensé lo mismo. Son dos senoidales desfasadas una 90 grados respecto de la otra (están en cuadratura).

@tac Ven pues, pon tu respuesta. :)

@Lambie la respuesta ya está, no agregaría información significativa. Es sólo una suerte de "especulación" sobre el significado literario de la estrofa :)

@Marce :| jaja, tienes razón, de todas formas sigue sin ser mi poesía favorita, pero ciertamente no aplica la lógica a la poesía. :D
